Bash: Is $1=$2 possible?
I want to create a function that assigns the contents of $2 to a variable, which is named the contents of $1. Eg:
self_assign() {
  eval $1=$2
  echo $1
}

If the variable expansion is carried out as expected, eval $1=$2 should be equals to Ushuaia=Argentina, and echo $Ushuaia would return Argentina.
But instead:
self_assign Ushuaia Argentina

Returns:
Ushuaia

Hence we are are only calling echo $1 in the example.
If this is possible, I am curious to know if eval $1=$1 would also be equal to writing Ushuaia=Ushuaia, where echo $Ushuaia" whould return Ushuaia.

echo ${!1} will do indirect evaluation.
